# What does 'born' mean in a product's "born on date"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Is the date on my Fickle Pickles® jar the expiration date?
>   No, our products are manufactured with a **born** on date. Fickle Pickles® will be good 18 months after the date on the jar.

What does "born" mean in this quote?  It is from [a pickle company's FAQ](http://www.ficklepickles.com/faq/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Born on date

simply means the date when it was produced (manufactured date).
It's just a fancy way of saying it.